Shorter Magic Link and Onebox
The current magic link can be used by typing [reverseengineering.se] which is a pretty long name. It takes a fair bit of time to type this in comments and chat.
Is it possible to alias [re.se] to point to the site? Its much shorter, and easier to use.
